# vim-airline status bar not shown when only single file is open

Tags: vim, gvim

I am recently start using Vim (Vim-gnome) and also use plugin vim-airline. Everything is  fine but when i have only single file open, Status bar shown but not rendered correctly(not exact airline bar, no color). but if I have more then one file everything looks fine.

Any solution please?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Put de following line in your .vimrc:

```
set laststatus=2
```

This helped me on the commandline :)

Comment: i have set laststatus=2 in my .vimrc, 2 solve the problem thanx